# Need to exclude some external links from receiving this notification

Tags: jquery, notifications

I am using this code to notify a user they are going to a 3rd party site but I want to exclude some URLs that are external. How/where can I do that in this code?

```
<script>
   $('a').each(function() {
      if (this.href !== "#" && this.href.indexOf('/') !== 0 && this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) === -1) {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
          .click(function() {        return confirm('NOTICE: You are leaving our website and will enter a website maintained by a third party. We are providing a link to the third party website solely as a convenience to you, because we believe that website may provide useful content. We are not, by referring or linking to the third party website, incorporating its contents into our own website. We do not endorse or guarantee, and we disclaim any responsibility for: the content, products or services offered on that website, its performance or interaction with your computer, its security and privacy policies and practices, and any consequences that may result from visiting that website. By clicking OK, you acknowledge this statement.');
       });
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if the site is within a white list. So you will need to create something to allow you to check a list if sites.

I also would recommend that you extract the logic to a function to make it a bit easier to maintain.

```
  function IsNoticeRequired(url)
  {      
      // Makes dealing with exclusions easier.
      url = url.toLowerCase();

      // Put the white listed sites here.
      var excludedSites = 
      [
          "stackoverflow.com"       
      ];

      // Determine if the site is in the exclusion list.
      var isInExclusion = false;
      for(var i = 0; i < excludedSites.length; i++)
      {
          // Need to check if url contains site.
          if(url.indexOf(excludedSites[i]) !== -1)
          {
              isInExclusion = true;
              break;
          }
      }

      var isNoticeRequired = url !== "#";
      isNoticeRequired = isNoticeRequired && url.indexOf("/") !== 0
      isNoticeRequired = isNoticeRequired && url.indexOf(location.hostname) === -1;
      isNoticeRequired = isNoticeRequired && !isInExclusion;

      return isNoticeRequired;
  }

$('a').each(function() {
  if (IsNoticeRequired(this.href)) {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank')
      .click(function() {        return confirm('NOTICE: You are leaving our website and will enter a website maintained by a third party. We are providing a link to the third party website solely as a convenience to you, because we believe that website may provide useful content. We are not, by referring or linking to the third party website, incorporating its contents into our own website. We do not endorse or guarantee, and we disclaim any responsibility for: the content, products or services offered on that website, its performance or interaction with your computer, its security and privacy policies and practices, and any consequences that may result from visiting that website. By clicking OK, you acknowledge this statement.');
   });
  }
});
```

JSFiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/9n7v67xa/

Comment: I replaced stackflow.com above with a URL that I would like to be excluded from the notification, replaced all of the previous code with this but it's not working for me. Everything is opened without a notification now. Thank you for trying!